# Powershell - Add a new document to exisitng word file with page number of 2

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am trying to open an existing word file and add a new page to it. This new page will have some content and I always want this page to be at the position number 2. So, the first page will always be same and every new content added should go to the second page. So far the code I have is as follows:

```
$day = get-date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
$filedate = Get-Date -Format "dd/MMM/yy - H tt"
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$doc = $word.documents.open("$home\desktop\Network Report.docx")
$selection = $word.selection
$Selection.InsertNewPage() #So, this page should be added at number 2
$selection.Font.Size = 14 
$selection.Font.color ="wdColorBlack"
$selection.TypeText("Network Report for $filedate")
$selection.TypeParagraph()
$selectimage =  $selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture("$home\desktop\screenshot.jpeg")
$selection.TypeParagraph()
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1);
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1);
$Footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1);
$Header.Range.Text = "$campus Network Report - $day "
$doc.save()
```

I tried different following after going through different forms:

```
$gotoPage1 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage 
$gotoNext1 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute
$gotoCount1 = null
$gotoName1 = 1
$Selection.GoTo([ref]$gotoPage1, [ref]$gotoNext1, [ref]$gotoCount1, [ref]$gotoName1)
```

But I've had no luck. How do I add a new page as the second page?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that should create page number two, and place the cursor there. This should work no matter the number of pages in the document.

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.Visible = $true

$doc = $word.documents.open("$home\desktop\Network Report.docx")

[Void]$word.Selection.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem]::wdGoToPage,
                     [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,
                     1 #page number
                     )
$doc.Bookmarks.Item("\page").range.select()
$word.Selection.Collapse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection]::wdCollapseEnd)
$word.Selection.InsertNewPage()
[Void]$word.Selection.GoTo([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem]::wdGoToPage,
                 [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection]::wdGoToAbsolute,
                 2 #page number
                 )
```